# Retrofit Moshi How to convert an array of objects with different fields to POJO

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I had a really hard time thinking how to convert the following JSON to Moshi data class. I cannot change how the API works either because the API is not mine.

The JSON is at below:

```
{
            "relationships": [
                {
                    "id": "66a36824-04e6-452c-b9d2-679ac589cb8a",
                    "type": "artist",
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "Nyunyu",
                        "imageUrl": null,
                        "biography": [],
                        "createdAt": "2021-04-19T21:59:45+00:00",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-04-19T21:59:45+00:00",
                        "version": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "a050afdf-7377-4fe6-8317-fe7b38d1e000",
                    "type": "cover_art",
                    "attributes": {
                        "description": "",
                        "volume": null,
                        "fileName": "b0d63a0b-dd95-468c-b3e1-098e1414f6e9.jpg",
                        "createdAt": "2021-05-24T18:35:46+00:00",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-05-24T18:35:46+00:00",
                        "version": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

I find out that it is impossible to convert because if you have an array of identical objects, then each object must share the same structure right! But in this case, I was forced to do it like this. Notice they have totally different fields.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Attributes (
   @Json(name = "name") val name : String,
   @Json(name = "imageUrl") val imageUrl : String,
   @Json(name = "biography") val biography : List<String>,
   @Json(name = "createdAt") val createdAt : String,
   @Json(name = "updatedAt") val updatedAt : String,
   @Json(name = "version") val version : Int
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Attributes (
   @Json(name = "description") val description : String,
   @Json(name = "volume") val volume : String,
   @Json(name = "fileName") val fileName : String,
   @Json(name = "createdAt") val createdAt : String,
   @Json(name = "updatedAt") val updatedAt : String,
   @Json(name = "version") val version : Int
)
```

And of course, it can't compile because we can't have two classes with same name. So what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Moshi custom converter, probably need to create 2 classes, like `ArtistAttributes` and `CoverArtAttributes` which inherits some of their common properties from a base `Attributes` class. Then in the custom converter you check for the type json property, if it equals `covert_art` you create a CoverArtAttributes object otherwise you create the other one.

Then in you parent class you should have something like:

```
data class Relationship constructor (
   @Json(name = "id") val id : String,
   @Json(name = "type") val type : String,
   @Json(name = "attributes") val attributes : Attributes,
)
```

```
class AttributesAdapter {
  @ToJson
  fun toJson(Attributes attributes): String {
    //ignore if you don't need opposite conversion
  }

  @FromJson
  fun fromJson(String json): Attributes {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)
    val type = jsonObject.getString("type")
    val adapter = when (type) {
      "artist" -> { 
        moshi.adapter(ArtistAttributes::class.java)
      }
      "cover_art" -> { 
        moshi.adapter(CoverArtAttributes::class.java)
      }
      else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unhandled type")
    }
    return adapter.fromJson(json)
  }
}
```

Then you need to add the `AttributesAdapter` to the parent Moshi instance and use it to convert the JSON.

> PS: The above code has not been tested, you probably will need to make
> adjustments to make it work but it can give you some hints.

For more info about this topic search for `Moshi custom adapters` on Internet, there are some useful resources around

Comment: Thanks man! Your answer has given me some ideas like downcasting the parent object to its child depending on its `type`.

Comment: Glad it helped to point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading MatPag's answer, I decided to use interface to achieve my goal. And this is my end result by using `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory`

1. Include the Moshi adapter dependency in your app module Gradle.

```
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshiadapters:$moshi_version"
```

2. Create your base interface which shares the same field

```
interface BaseRelationship {
    val type: String
}
```

3. Create your data classes implementing the interface in Step 2

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class RelArtist(
    @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
    @Json(name = "type") override val type: String,
    @Json(name = "attributes") val attributes: RelArtistAttr?
): BaseRelationship

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class RelArtistAttr(
    @Json(name = "name") val name : String?,
    @Json(name = "imageUrl") val imageUrl : String?,
    @Json(name = "biography") val biography : List<String>,
    @Json(name = "createdAt") val createdAt : String?,
    @Json(name = "updatedAt") val updatedAt : String?,
    @Json(name = "version") val version : Int?
)
```

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class RelCoverImage(
    @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
    @Json(name = "type") override val type: String,
    @Json(name = "attributes") val attributes: RelCoverImageAttr?
) : BaseRelationship

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class RelCoverImageAttr(
    @Json(name = "description") val description: String?,
    @Json(name = "volume") val volume: String?,
    @Json(name = "fileName") val fileName: String?,
    @Json(name = "createdAt") val createdAt: String?,
    @Json(name = "updatedAt") val updatedAt: String?,
    @Json(name = "version") val version: Int?
)
```

4. In your `Retrofit` instance, do this.

```
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(BaseRelationship::class.java, "type")
            .withSubtype(RelArtist::class.java, "artist")
            .withSubtype(RelCoverImage::class.java, "cover_art")
        )
        .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(MangadexService.BASE_URL)
        .client(httpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(MangadexService::class.java)
```

Step 5. In your API calls, cast it to appropriate type depending on what is inside of your base interface

```
val relationship = it.relationships.firstOrNull { it.type == "cover_art" }
val coverImageRelation = relationship as? RelCoverImage

// Do things with your downcasted object here. . .
```